# Using VBA to set passwords to edit different ranges

Tags: vba, passwords, range

I am trying to write a code that will ask for a password to open an Excel file. There should be three passwords (e.g. America, Asia, Europe). Depending on the password entered, only certain range should be enabled for editing (e.g. "America" for A2:A100, "Asia" for B2:B100, "Europe" for C2:C100).

Answer (score 1):

Set up your workbook as follows:

1. select each of your ranges and assign them a name - America, Asia and Europe
2. Add the following code to the workbook

   Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   ```
   Dim password As String

   password = InputBox("Password", "Please enter the password")

   Dim worksheetpassword As String

   worksheetpassword = "password"

   If password = "AmericaPassword" Then

       ActiveSheet.Unprotect (worksheetpassword)

       ActiveSheet.Range("America").Locked = False
       ActiveSheet.Range("Asia").Locked = True
       ActiveSheet.Range("Europe").Locked = True

       ActiveSheet.Protect (worksheetpassword)

   ElseIf password = "AsiaPassword" Then
       ActiveSheet.Unprotect (worksheetpassword)

       ActiveSheet.Range("America").Locked = True
       ActiveSheet.Range("Asia").Locked = False
       ActiveSheet.Range("Europe").Locked = True

       ActiveSheet.Protect (worksheetpassword)


   ElseIf password = "EuropePassword" Then
       ActiveSheet.Unprotect (worksheetpassword)

       ActiveSheet.Range("America").Locked = True
       ActiveSheet.Range("Asia").Locked = True
       ActiveSheet.Range("Europe").Locked = False

       ActiveSheet.Protect (worksheetpassword)

   Else
       ActiveSheet.Unprotect (worksheetpassword)

       ActiveSheet.Range("America").Locked = True
       ActiveSheet.Range("Asia").Locked = True
       ActiveSheet.Range("Europe").Locked = True

       ActiveSheet.Protect (worksheetpassword)

       MsgBox ("You cannot edit this file")

   End If
   ```

   End Sub
3. Password protect your workbook - the code assumes a password of "password"

Close the workbook and reopen, you will be prompted for a password.  If you enter "AmericaPassword" you should be able to modify the "America" range, "AsiaPassword" to modify the "Asia" range etc.